# Is there a difference between a button#classname and a button.classname in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am a newbie in JavaScript and I currently have a script that presses a button for me. I tried it on one website and it worked great. Now I did the exact same thing on another website and it wouldn't work. The differences I could spot in HTML were that when I hovered over it with the element selector, one button had was formatted as `button#id.class` and the other one was just `button.class`. The two are also have some different attributes, but I think most of them are just website dependent.

So here is the HTML of the first button:

```html
<button id="id" class="classname" type="button">Button</button>
```

Here is the HTML of the second button, I removed the svg data since I don't think it's necessary, I can add it later if you need it:

```html
<button class="classname" aria-label="aria label" title="title"><svg></svg></button>
```

Here is the line of JavaScript that actually presses the button, at least the second one:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('classname')[0].click()
```

Comment: Are you asking [What is the difference between id and class in CSS, and when should I use them?](/q/12889362/4642212) (and [What's the difference between an id and a class?](/q/544010/4642212))?

Comment: @SebastianSimon As I stated at the beginning, I am a complete newbie to JavaScript. I could be asking this, I can't be sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `.` before a string in a selector indicates a class. So `.class` will select an element with the class of `class`.

A `#` before a string in a selector indicates an ID. So `#foo` will select an element with the ID of `foo`.

So

```
button#id.class
```

means nearly the same thing as

```
button.class
```

except that the first also has an ID of `id`.

Because IDs should be unique, this

```
button#id.class
```

should also be equivalent to just

```
#id
```

> ```
> document.getElementsByClassName('classname')[0].click()
> ```

If you only need a single element, use `querySelector` instead - no need to retrieve the whole collection.

```
document.querySelector('.classname').click();
```

Comment: or `document.querySelectorAll('.classname')[0].click()`

Comment: If there is a space in the classname, should I leave it or add a `.`

Comment: @gurkensaas A space in a selector means something completely different - it's the descendant selector. Eg `#foo .bar` will select the child here: `<div id="foo"><span class="bar">`. A space in the class name indicates multiple classes, so the most precise way to do it would be to list both, eg `<span class="foo bar">` with `span.foo.bar.`

Comment: Your answer didn't exactly solve my problem but it pointed me in the right direction. I used `document.getElementById('Id').click();` and it worked great.